# Fingerprints matching and identification

Tags: vb.net-to-c#

I am developing a Windows application using VB.NET for a fingerprint identification system to match with the same individual fingerprints stored in my database SQL server.

I heard of hardware to collect those fingerprints from the scene and analyze them, but I don't know the full procedure.

Secondly, how can my system extract the minutaes, or details, from the two  fingerprint images to determine whether they both came from the same person or not?

Answer (score 0):

There is a company called [Verifinger](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verifinger.html), they offer SDK for Windows applications you can use in your application.